# Facebook API: How to post to group wall without login?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, codeigniter

I want to post to my own group(I'm admin) wall a text but without to login first because it should be done automatically. How could I do that? Or is it even possible?

I'm using codeigniter (php) and javascript.

Comment: Surely in order to know that you're the admin, you'll have to log in to the API first?

Comment: These kind of questions scare me.

Comment: Nearly a month later and still no acceptance of former answers. We'd probably help you if you contributed back to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Sure this is not possible. You need to be logged on and have valid access token + good permissions (publish_stream) to be able to post somewhere

Answer (score 0):

The group access is little bit buggy on Facebook, check my latest bug report:

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19157